# iOS - WKWebView not added correctly to its subView in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, wkwebview

I'm trying to add programatically a `WKWebView` to my `webViewContainer` (type = `UIVIew`) as a `subView`. The code bellow works perfectly when I test it in an iPhone 11 iOS 13.3 but not in the iPhone 6 iOS 11.0.1. The problem is that the `webViewContainer` has `leading` (value = 10) and `trailing` (value = 10) spaces with the `self.view`. When I run it in the iPhone 6, only the `leading` is respected and not the `trailing` also. When I debug, the `webViewContainer` and my added `webView` is getting the same frame as it's `webViewContainer`.

What can be the problem?

```
       let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.frame.size = self.webViewContainer.frame.size
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
```

Comment: could you share your constraint codes if you don't mind ?

Comment: @sekoyaz I make the constraints from the xib file

Comment: before adding as a subview put and
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, can you check out ?

Comment: @sekoyaz okay I will check it now

Comment: @sekoyaz I add your line exactly before the addSubView but it has no effect

Comment: I am sorry, i will think about this

Comment: @sekoyaz no problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Frame property of any kind of view consists four properties: x, y, width and height. In your code, the only thing you do is to set width and height properties with the following code;

```
webView.frame.size = self.webViewContainer.frame.size
```

I believe your webViewContainer has x: 0 and y: 0 values and since you initialized your webView with .zero frame, the values are the same. **However, that might not be the case always.** It will cause trouble when a change in webViewContainer frame is requested.

If I am not mistaken, you would like your webView to have be exactly on the same spot with your webViewContainer. To achieve that, the difference between frame and bounds properties should be explained.

**Frame** is the relative position of a view to its parent view. However **bounds** property refers to its coordinates relative to its own space.

With these difference explained, to achieve what you want to do, it is relatively safer to simply replace this line;

```
webView.frame.size = self.webViewContainer.frame.size
```

with following;

```
webView.frame = webViewContainer.bounds
webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

autoresizing mask property will change your webView's frame when the bounds of the superview (in this case webViewContainer) changes.